# Name for global collection to be populated by plugins

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

What would you call this type of object:

A global collection of a certain type of object, to which plugins add their implementations.

Like a key hook, on which you hang your keys. The global collection is the key hook here, which all parts of the system know how to locate. Then, each plugin can add an implementation (a key) to the collection (key hook).

Lets imagine each object is a `UIComponentFactory`. What would you call the global collection of `UIComponentFactories`?

`UIComponentFactoryRepository`? `UIComponentFactoryRegistry`?

Comment: `UIComponentFactoryProvider` or `UIComponentServiceProvider`?

Comment: Provider sounds like a container that contains exactly one instance. I want to indicate that this a container of more than one instance, which can be added to. So far registry wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe may be the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Or the [Extensibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility_pattern) a.k.a. *Framework*

Take a look which one matches your use case best. Then use their wording.